# Residue at infinity doesnt depend on the radius

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, proof-verification, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

So i've been asked to show that $Res(f,\infty)$ does not depend on the radius R. but first let me give you some back story here.

> let $f: \mathbb{C} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be analytic, except for a finite number of poles $\{z_1,z_2,...,z_m\}$ and define the residue of f at infinity to be
>   $$ Res(f,\infty) = -\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{S_{R}^{+}(0)}f(z)dz$$
>   Where $R > 0$ is so large that f has no singularities in $A_{R,\infty}(0)$
>   Show that $Res(f,\infty)$ does not depend on R
>
> Note: Where $S_R^{+}(0)$ is the positively orientated circle around $0$ of radius R (eg, $|z| = R$)

now, i've found this to be a little confusing anyway since we've had to define R large enough to accept all singularities of f. So please by all means extend a helping hand if you see that i'm doing this complete wrong.

The only major thinking i can consider is this. Since
$$ Res(f,\infty) = -\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{S_{R}^{+}(0)}f(z)dz$$
we can rewrite this to be the sum of the residues but we could also consider the Cauchy-Goursat Theorem, and essentially the contour $S_{R}^{+}(0)$ will simply be replaced by a sum of smaller contours each containing only a single singularity.

ie. $$Res(f,\infty) = -\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{s_{R}^{+}(0)}f(z)dz = -\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\int_{S_{\epsilon}^{+}(z_i)}f(z)~dz$$ where $\epsilon>0$ is large enough to capture the single singularity with in question. (for argument sake we could take it to be 1)

Am i on the right lines? is this correct? and if so, how can i make this rigorous (though the last part is not necessary).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It can be turned into a correct proof, but longer than necessary. Instead, you can aim to answer directly what they asked. You have the formula with certain radius $R$, check that the formula yield the same value if you replace $R$ by some $R'>R$. To do this apply Cauchy's theorem to the contour formed by traversing $S_R^{+}$, then move to $S_{R'}$ along a radius, and follow $S_{R'}^{-}$.

Comment: Edit:: (Ok, i'll follow your suggestion)

well, the only other avenue i can think of is the fact that
Since $Res(f,\infty) = -Res(\frac{1}{z^2}f(\frac{1}{z}),0)$ it doesnt matter what the size of contour is, since at most we're just calculating a single point, ie $z=0$

Comment: Yes, even that, if you already know that formula.

Comment: what means $A_{R,\infty }$?